# Calling the PredicateContext.Consumer property for a conditional registration that is requested directly from the container is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

I am trying to register conditionally (based on implementation type) a custom ApiClient using SimpleInjector as can be seen in the following function.

```
private static void RegisterEndpoint<TServiceType>(
    string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    var registration =
        Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration<IMyApiClient<HttpClient>>(
            () => new MyApiClient<HttpClient>(param1, param2, param3),
            container);

    container.RegisterConditional<IMyApiClient<HttpClient>>(
        registration,
        c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(TServiceType));
 }
```

However when loading the asp.net page I get the following error:

> Calling the PredicateContext.Consumer property for a conditional
> registration that is requested directly from the container is not
> supported. IMyApiClient<HttpClient> is requested directly from the
> container opposed to it being injected into another class, which
> causes this exception. If IMyApiClient<HttpClient> needs to be
> requested directly (e.g. by calling
> container.GetInstance<IMyApiClient<HttpClient>>()), check the
> PredicateContext.HasConsumer property inside the predicate to
> determine whether PredicateContext.Consumer can be called, e.g.
> container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IMyApiClient<>),
> typeof(IMyApiClient<>), c => c.HasConsumer ?
> c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(MyConsumer) : true). Only call
> PredicateContext.Consumer when PredicateContext.HasConsumer returns
> true.

`IMyApiClient<HttpClient>` is not requested directly from the container anywhere in the code. It's only being injected in a few constructors.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this problem by providing us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Hi doorman. As it currently stands, your question unfortunately has too little information to be answered. Please update your question with the suggestions provided in my previous comment and post a comment when you did that. Using this information I'll likely be able to help you and answer your question.

Comment: Hi @Steven thanks for reaching out. I changed the implementation a bit so now I can simply use RegisterInstance instead.